# oversampling doesn't generate new samples

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, oversampling, imblearn

My dataset has the following distribution:

```
class   frequency
0         960
1         2093
2         22696
3         1116
4         2541
5         1298
6         14
```

I am using `python-imblearn` to oversample the minority class. With `regular` smote I am able to generate 200 samples of class 6 but with `l1borderline` or `l2borderline` I am not able to do so.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm=SMOTE(ratio={6:200})

# output
>>> Presampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 14})
>>> resampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 200})



sm=SMOTE(kind='borderline1',ratio={6:200})

# output
>>> Presampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 14})
>>> resampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 14})

sm=SMOTE(kind='borderline2',ratio={6:200})

# output
>>> Presampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 14})
>>> resampled shape Counter({2: 22696, 4: 2541, 1: 2093, 5: 1298, 3: 1116, 0: 960, 6: 14})
```

Is there something mathematical or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/36

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks for the link, seems that it  is something mathematical. When I tried `sm=SMOTE(kind='borderline1',ratio={6:200,4:4000,0:2000})` samples for class-2 and class-4 were generated but not for class-6. May be the information is too less for the variants of SMOTE to generate samples.